# What do skipped, rescued, and ignored results mean in ANSIBLE playbook execution?

Tags: ansible, automation, networking

What do skipped, rescued, and ignored results mean in an Ansible playbook execution?
What would be a possible scenario where these results would be different from 0?

```yaml
PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************
localhost: ok=3 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

Comment: could you please provide a text version of the screenshot, making it easier to read and more accessible? thanks!

Comment: I did it. Thank you for having pointed to that.

Answer (score 4):

For example, the play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: Task will be SKIPPED
      debug:
        msg: You will never see this message.
      when: false

    - name: Failed command will be IGNORED
      command: /usr/bin/false
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: Failed command will be RESCUED
      block:
        - command: /usr/bin/false
      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ ansible_failed_result }}"
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************
localhost: ok=2 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=1 rescued=1 ignored=1
```

For details see

- [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#error-handling-in-playbooks)
- [Handling errors with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks)

Briefly, an error is ignored when you set `ignore_errors: true`. This can be set on multiple levels. See [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). If you use `block/rescue` you can actively handle the consequences of the error.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear now to me.